# using GDAL/OGR (faster)

Tags: gdal, c++, visual-studio, osgeo

Eventually, I was able to get the GDAL installed and compiled correctly using Visual C++ 2010. I even tested some of its methods on some geo-referenced raster files, and it looks like that all is working fine. However, I am interested in running GDAL with some sort of hardware acceleration? Does anyone know if there is any support for GDAL with some acceleration libraries (e.g. CUDA/OepnCL, or maybe even with using OpenGL for the sake of GPGPU, or SIMD)?

Comment: Why did you compile GDAL?

Comment: +1, there are a lot of builds available from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/